# load or play some javascript code when a div is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code

```js
        var GetMsg;
        var MsgIndex=0;
        window.onload=function(){
        var params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
        var param = params.get("m");
        if(param){
        GetMsg = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(param)));
        console.log(GetMsg);
        DisplayLetter();
        }
  
        };
        function DisplayLetter(){
        var msg=GetMsg.charAt(MsgIndex).toUpperCase();
        var audio = new Audio('bip.wav');
        MsgIndex++;
        if(MsgIndex<=GetMsg.length){
        if(msg!==" "){ //Current character is not a space
        $('.'+msg).html('<img class="bulbOn" src="images/bulbOn.png"/>');
        audio.play();
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.'+msg).html('<img class="bulbOff" src="images/bulbOff.png"/>');
        DisplayLetter();
        }, 1000);
        }else{
        msg="[Space]";
        setTimeout(DisplayLetter, 2000);
        }
        }


function runAnimation() {
  document.getElementById("playBg").style.display = "none";
  }
```

But I want to run the main javascript code (from var GetMsg;) and place it inside the function runAnimation. so when I click this div with the onclick=""runAnimation()" the entire javascript will load:)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery.

```
$('#playBg').on('click', function() {
     // Here will be your code which start after click.
});
```

Comment: the playBg is turned off (display:none) with the button div id="playButton" onclick="runAnimation()" value="send">Play</div> but what I'm trying to do is that, when the function runAnimation() is clicked to load inside all the javascript code remaining :( @Simion